# Combining every 2 frames into one, creating a 30 FPS video out of 60, possible?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, frame, frame-rate, blend

I've got a 60 FPS video, but it has some noise. Is there a way, somehow, for a program to combine every 2 frames into 1 (not dismissing but combining and blending), and create a 30 FPS video? I don't know what it will look like but it would be a nice experiment.

Comment: Use `select` filter to split even & odd frames into 2 streams and `mix` filter to combine them.